# Wrapping all elements with href attribute using XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt, xhtml

I want to wrap any tag that contains a href attribute into an <a> tag.

eg.

```
<img src="someimage.jpg" href="someurl.xml"/>
```

would become:

```
<a href="someurl.xml"><img src="someimage.jpg"/></a>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output indent="yes"/>
    <!--standard identity template that just copies content -->
    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <!--For every element that has an href attribute-->
    <xsl:template match="*[@href]">
     <!--create an anchor element and an href attribute 
          with the value of the matched element's href attribute-->
        <a href="{@href}">
                   <!--then copy the matched element -->
            <xsl:copy>
                         <!--then apply templates (which will either match the 
                              identity template above or this template,
                              if any child elements have href attributes) -->
                <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
            </xsl:copy>
        </a>
    </xsl:template>

    <!--redact the href attribute-->
    <xsl:template match="*/@href"/>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: This transformation doesn't produce the result that the OP wants.

Answer (score 0):

**This transformation**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
     <xsl:copy>
       <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
     </xsl:copy>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="*[@href]">
  <a href="{@href}">
   <xsl:copy>
     <xsl:apply-templates select=
         "node()|@*[not(name()='href')]"/>
   </xsl:copy>
  </a>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when applied on the provided XML document**:

```
<img src="someimage.jpg" href="someurl.xml"/>
```

**produces exactly the wanted, correct result** (unlike the other answer):

```
<a href="someurl.xml">
   <img src="someimage.jpg"/>
</a>
```

**Explanation**: **[Identity rule](http://dpawson.co.uk/xsl/sect2/identity.html)**, overriden for any element that has an `href` attribute.